# JSPDF/html2canvas cutting line text in half

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

[image]

How can i prevent jspdf from cutting words in half. When converting from HTML to pdf directly.

Here is my code.

```js
const onFinish = async (data) => {

        const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        document.getElementById('print').style.overflow = 'scroll';
        const opt = {
            callback: async function (doc) {
                window.open(
                    doc.output('bloburl', { filename: cvCopy?.cvDocName }),
                    '_blank',
                );
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            margin: [30, 30, 30, 30],
            autoPaging: 'text',
            html2canvas: {
                scale: 0.7,
                scrollY: -window.scrollY,
                // width: 595,
                height: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
                windowHeight: window.outerHeight + window.innerHeight,
            },
        };

        doc.html(document.getElementById('print'), opt);
    };
```